# Resetting a Boolean variable in Java

Tags: java

I am currently writing a program that generates a new object once the previous object meets the conditions of a boolean variable to return true. The problem I am having is that I am working with multiple different shapes. The program works perfectly until a second type of shape displays. At that point it has two shapes meeting their boolean isDone() conditions. Is there an easy way to return a boolean variable to being false/its default condition?

Code:

```
if (baserectangle.isDone()) {
    int meowchoice = (int) Math.round(2 * Math.random());
    if (meowchoice < 1) {
        baserectangle = (new Rectangle(10, 25, position, m, n));
        scene1.add(baserectangle);
    }
    if (meowchoice >= 1) {
        basesquare = (new Square(10, 25, position, m, n));
        scene1.add(basesquare);     
    }}
else if (basesquare.isDone()) {
    int meowchoice2 = (int) Math.round(2 * Math.random());
    if (meowchoice2 < 1) {
        baserectangle = (new Rectangle(10, 25, position, m, n));
        scene1.add(baserectangle);
    }
    if (meowchoice2 >= 1) {
        basesquare = (new Square(10, 25, position, m, n));
        scene1.add(basesquare); 
    }


}
```

i.e. the program starts with a baserectangle or basesquare and then when that shape meets its isDone condition, randomly generates a new baserectangle or basesquare. The problem is that once both a baserectangle and a basesquare exist, it continually generates more than one shape at a time.

isDone() implementation:

```
public boolean isDone() {
    if (this.y < 2) {
        return true;
    }
    if (i > 0 && position [i-1][j] != 0) {
    return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

where this.y is the y coordinate of the shape on the plane and i and j are the object's position within the array.

Comment: Are any of your fields static?

Comment: The only thing that's static is the shape's color. It's x and y coordinates change as does its place within the position array

Comment: What governs `isDone` then?  Could you include the implementation of that?

Comment: Edit it into your question.  Comments aren't meant for this.  Also, include the field declaration(s) that the method relies on.

Comment: @Makoto Added to the opening post

Comment: So, each shape has it's own `int[][] position?`

Answer (score 0):

You could put another variabile in your class, for example `alreadyDone` and use it to decide if it has to generate other shapes or not, for example:

```
public boolean isDone() {
if (this.y < 2) {
    alreadyDone = true;
    return true;
}
if (i > 0 && position [i-1][j] != 0) {
    alreadyDone = true;
    return true;
}
else return false;
}
```

and during the check:

```
if (!baserectangle.alreadyDone  && baserectangle.isDone()) { ...
```

Keep in mind this is just an example, I'm sure there are better ways to do this

Answer (score 0):

> The program works perfectly until a second type of shape displays. At that point it has two shapes meeting their boolean isDone() conditions

Sure, you have two shapes. The problem probably lies the the fact that you only ever check that **one** is done with an `if-else if` combination.

You probably need to check if **either** shape is done with separate if statements.

```
// Rectangle is done
if (baserectangle.isDone()) {
    int meowchoice = (int) Math.round(2 * Math.random());
    if (meowchoice < 1) {
        baserectangle = (new Rectangle(10, 25, position, m, n));
        scene1.add(baserectangle);
    }
    else if (meowchoice >= 1) {
        basesquare = (new Square(10, 25, position, m, n));
        scene1.add(basesquare);     
    }
}

// Square is done
if (basesquare.isDone()) {
    int meowchoice2 = (int) Math.round(2 * Math.random());
    if (meowchoice2 < 1) {
        baserectangle = (new Rectangle(10, 25, position, m, n));
        scene1.add(baserectangle);
    }
    else if (meowchoice2 >= 1) {
        basesquare = (new Square(10, 25, position, m, n));
        scene1.add(basesquare); 
    }
}
```

However, the content of those two if-statements are the exact same, so you can do like so

```
// Rectangle or Square are done
if (baserectangle.isDone() || basesquare.isDone()) {
    int meowchoice = (int) Math.round(2 * Math.random());
    if (meowchoice < 1) {
        baserectangle = (new Rectangle(10, 25, position, m, n));
        scene1.add(baserectangle);
    }
    else if (meowchoice >= 1) {
        basesquare = (new Square(10, 25, position, m, n));
        scene1.add(basesquare);     
    }
}
```

And if you want to shorten the `isDone` method...

```
public boolean isDone() {
    return (this.y < 2) || (i > 0 && position [i-1][j] != 0);
}
```